# how to do spring javaconfig inheritance

Tags: spring-java-config

How do I make a javaconfig version for the below?

```
<bean id="parentDao" class="com.MyHibernateDao">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="childDao" class="com.ChildHibernateImpl" parent="parentDao"/>
```

(btw, Is there any documentation for Spring Javaconfig?)

Regards,
j

Comment: Why not directly use inheritance in Java by extends keyword?

Comment: I re-read the Spring Reference 4.0.9  (http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-child-bean-definitions).  The usage of the 'parent' attribute in the code I mentioned, is like a 'templating' technique.  There is no mention of a way to do 'inheritance' in JavaConfig  (at least in the Spring Reference), in the same semantics as java 'extends' inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have researched, there is no templating way that is similar to the XML sample shown, where the 'parent' attribute is used.