# Create spring annotated bean that inherits from xml-bean

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have 2 classes.

```
public class Parent {
  //...some properties, for Example
  public setFoo(String foo);
  public setBar(String bar);
}      

public class Child extends Parent {
}
```

And I have xml spring config.

```
//yes, id don't match class name, I can't change it
<bean id="parent_dir" class="Parent">
   <property name="foo" ref="<some another xml bean>"/>
   <property name="bar" ref="<yet another xml bean>"/>    
</bean>

<bean id="child" class="Child" parent="parent_dir"/>
```

I need move bean "child" in Java Spring Config, but bean "parent_dir" must remain in xml config.
I tried make Child class autowired and Import xml. Yes, child bean have been created without errors, but properties remained uninitialized.
How I can make this right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28927089/how-to-do-spring-javaconfig-inheritance